# Big Prime Numbers in c

Tags: c, windows, primes

I doing another question from the Eular problems page. 
The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I've managed to write the code below but i think somewhere along the line (namely when we get to big prime numbers) the code loses accuracy. The answer should be 142913828922 but i get 1179908154.

I dont know why im not getting the answer because the code below works for under 10.

Any help would be great. the reason im doing these problems is to get better at C.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Initialise */
void CalcNumber(unsigned long number);
int isPrime(unsigned long number);

/* Functions*/

void CalcNumber(unsigned long number)
{
    unsigned long i = 1;
    unsigned long prime = 0;

    while(i != number)
    {
        i++;
        if(isPrime(i))
        {
            printf("prime: %lu\n", i);
            prime += i;
        }
    }

    printf("The sum of primes under %lu: %lu\n",number, prime);
    printf("count: %d\n", i);

}

int isPrime(unsigned long number)
{
      int i, nb, count, test,limit;
      test = count = 0;
      nb = number;
      limit = sqrt(nb) + 1;

      if(nb == 2)
      {
          return 1;
      }

      if (nb % 2 == 0)
              test = 1;
      else{
          for (i = 3 ; i < limit && ! test; i+=2, count++)
            if (nb % i == 0)
              test = 1;
      }
      if (!test)
              return 1;
      else
              return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long number;

    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%ul", &number );
    CalcNumber(number);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I could guess multiple questions, which is the one you want to get answered?

Comment: basically what am i missing? the answer is up there and im not getting it and i dont know why. the code above works for under 10 but not under two million.

Comment: What is the size of unsigned long on your computer? If you want it to work, the answer should be 64.

Comment: @spartan2417 How much long is your long? :-) And I'm not kidding. Under Windows it's still 32 bits, so not long enough.

Comment: You should post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . It is more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: Have a try on unsigned long long int then ;)

Comment: Thanks guys im gonna try that now, i just looked it up and your probably right, silly mistake. @Constantinius thats a good idea, i didnt even know that existed!

Comment: Yes, and if `unsigned long long` won't work, try `uint64_t` or `unsigned __int64` (depending on your compiler).

Comment: It worked, does one of you want to put it as an answer? and ill tick it.

Comment: @Constantinius: I disagree about `codereview`; their FAQ includes the line, [To the best of your knowledge, does the code work?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: If this _is_ a Windows system, could you add the windows tag to it? (I didn't realize `long` on Windows was only 32 bits long. Sheesh.)

Comment: @Xanatos: looks like you guessed correctly; you should add it as an answer. :)

Comment: @sarnold: the answer would be the same for 32 bit Linux, though, it's not just a Windows thing.

Comment: @SteveJessop The difference is that on 32 bit Linux, a `long` is still the size of a pointer, while on 64 bit Windows it isn't. So `long` being 32 bits isn't surprising on a 32 bit system, but may be on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @Daniel: I know why Linux chose LP64, but the size of a pointer has nothing to do with the questioner's code -- he wrongly expects `long` to hold a > 32 bit total. There's no indication that the question is about 64 bit Windows, or any 64 bit platform. So it's wrong for sarnold to exclaim "sheesh" as if `long` "should" be 64 bits, unless we're equally willing to exclaim "sheesh" in respect of 32 bit systems. The only non-sheesh 32 bit platform I can think of offhand, is that Java has a 64 bit `long` type even on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree, I just speculated on how that expectation came to be. I've heard/read 'long is the size of a pointer' so often, it seems to be a common misconception.

Comment: @Steve: I've fallen into the trap of assuming that `long` always matches the size of pointers. I _do_ live in an insular world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the length of the number you should use a data type long at least 64 bits. The newer C99 standard includes the `long long` (and `unsigned long long`) datatype that is at least 64 bits. If you need to `printf` them you have to use `"%lld"` and `"%llu"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void CalcNumber(unsigned long number)
{
    unsigned long i = 1;
    unsigned long prime = 0;

    while(i != number)
    {
        i++;
        if(isPrime(i))
        {
            printf("prime: %lu\n", i);
            prime += i;
        }
    }
```

Note that you're checking roughly twice as many numbers as you need to. The only even prime number is `2`, so there's no point checking anything other than odd numbers greater than or equal to `3` -- and add in `1+2` "by hand". You might as well use `i += 2;` here.

Your `isPrime()` method will re-calculate a lot of information. What PE is *really* getting at is using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to build a table of prime numbers and then sum the primes from *that*.

But if you'd really like to continue along with your current `isPrime()` method, I'd like to give a very strong hint that you drop the `test` variable completely and `return` from the method *immediately* when you know a number isn't prime. It will lead to code that is easier to read *and* easier to debug.

Consider writing some test cases that test `isPrime()` specifically. Check the Usual Suspects: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable storing the sum of the prime number is unsigned long and the unsigned long range is from 0 to 4294967295. It can't hold 142913828922 number. 
142913828922 mod (4294967295 + 1) = 1179908154

Change you data type